# How to change date time display format in View of MVC ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC application and I want to change the display format of the date in the view

Right now I have below comment you can see the date shown as it is from DB

**Akash Sharma** *put comment on* 3/7/2013 12:55:24 PM
Hi there....

I want to change it like --->    7 March 2013 12:55 PM

how to do this ?

I have written below code in the View.

`$('p.p12-'+'@ViewBag.EId').append('<br /><div style="background-color:#FAFAFA;">Recently Added... <br /><a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Employee", new { id = "__id__" })'.replace('__id__', data.OwnerID) + '">' + data.OwnerName +  '</a>'+ data.cmtDateTime + <input type="button" id=comment' + data.Id  + ' class="deleteComment" value="Delete" /><br/>' + data.msg + '<div>');`

Answer (score 0):

You could format the date in the controller action returning the view model. In the code you have shown you are using some `data.cmtDateTime` property where I suppose that `data` is the JSON result of a controller action you invoked with AJAX. So what you could do is use a view model and perform the formatting in your controller action:

```
public ActionResult GetComments()
{
    IEnumerable<Comment> comments = ...
    return Json(
        comments.Select(c => new 
        {
            cmtDateTime = c.cmtDateTime.ToString("d MMM yyyy hh:mm tt"),
            Id = c.Id,
            OwnerID = c.OwnerID,
            OwnerName = c.OwnerName,
            msg = c.msg
        }), 
        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the proper `ToString()` formatter. Here you have all explained: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx.